# What is causing this ArrayOutOfBoundsException in my array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyHashTable<K extends Comparable<K>, E> {

    private ArrayList<Entry<K,E>> bucket = new ArrayList<Entry<K,E>>();
    private int bucketSize;
    private int collisionCount = 0;

    // Constructor that takes number of buckets as input
    public MyHashTable( int len ) 
    {
        this.bucketSize = len;
        for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
        {
            bucket.set( i, null ); //ERROR APPEARS ON THIS LINE
        }
    }
```

and is evoked when I call from another method :

```
MyHashTable<MyString, AnimalRecord> linearProbing = new MyHashTable<MyString, AnimalRecord>(59);
linearProbing.put( lion.name, lion );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private ArrayList<Entry<K,E>> bucket = new ArrayList<Entry<K,E>>();
```

Creates an empty arrayList.

The [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element
>   Throws: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `index` is out of range (`index < 0 || index >= size()`)

So

```
bucket.set( i, null );
```

tries to set null to the `i`th element (starting at `0`). But the arraylist is empty, and that is why you get the exception.

What you want is the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
{
    bucket.add(null);
}
```

adds `null` to the end of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the error (mainly because I just added a size and the bug still occurred) - but can't a list grow with add - even if the size is empty?

Comment: @user3771739 A list *will* grow with `add`. It will not grow with `set`. You need to use `add` where you are using `set`.

Comment: Will it be 10th instead of the first? There is a default capacity in the intialization. http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html

Comment: @MingtaoZhang `capacity` is different from `size`. An ArrayList is backed by an array and `capacity` is the size of that array. Java manages the array (increase/decrease size etc) and mostly transparent. `size` is the actual number of elements in the `ArrayList`. `capacity >= size`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **add** not **set** at first sight.

Look at the [doc of set() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

You met with with the condition  `index >= size()`

Answer (score 1):

Initially, the `ArrayList` is empty, when you create a new instance of it:

```
private ArrayList<Entry<K,E>> bucket = new ArrayList<Entry<K,E>>();
```

When you are calling the `set` method on the `ArrayList`, you are trying to replace an existing element, which is not found, because the list is empty.

You should use `add`, instead of `set` if adding the element to the list is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You ArrayList (bucket) doesn't have any elements in it - bucket.set replaces an element, it doesn't insert an element.

See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Call ArrayList.add() instead as that will append an element to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Rather obvious I think, your ArrayList is created with default capacity (10), while you are trying to access indexes above it (up to 58).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java-Documentation for the Class ArrayList and the method you are using:

The method set "Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element."

At the time of your method call you do not have an ArrayList with an Element 59. The initial size of an ArrayList constructed with ArrayList() Standard-Constructor is 10.

You could use a constructor `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`

Find the documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html